# Using strlen() with Array Integers or Float

Tags: c

Is there a way, I can use of strlen() to find the length of the arrays, instead of specifying in the loop.
First Code: Working With **x < 4** Which is the size of the array of **temps[4]**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    float temps[4] = {72.5, 73.4, 74.7, 75.2};
    int x;
    printf("Local Temperatures\n");
    for(x = 1; x < 4; x++){
        printf("Station %d: %.1f\n",x,temps[x]);
    }
}
```

My Second Code, Not Working, But Looking At What, I Am Trying To achieve with strlen() to find the size of the array.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    float temps[4] = {72.5, 73.4, 74.7, 75.2};
    int x;
    float size;
    size = temps;
    printf("Local Temperatures\n");
    for(x = 1; x < strlen(size); x++){
        printf("Station %d: %.1f\n",x,size[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strlen` is for strings. Why do you think it would work for any other array type? To get the number of element of an array do `sizeof temps / sizeof temps[0]`.

Comment: What does your compiler put out if you enable all compiler warnings?  You need to do that.  What you are trying to do is unclear, and it's not proper C code.

Comment: 1. `strlen` is only for char* you can't use it for array. 2. temps can be indexed only from 0 to 3, array out of bound access is happening in your snippet

Comment: Tip: `float temps[] = ...;` is better than `float temps[4] = ...;`

Answer (score 3):

`strlen` is effectively an optimized version of the following:

```
size_t len = 0;
const char *p = s;
while (!*p) {
   ++len;
   ++p;
}
```

You can easily adapt that.

```
size_t len = 0;
const float *p = s;
while (*p != 0.0) {
   ++len;
   ++p;
}
```

Of course, that means you need a sentinel value just like you had for the string.

```
float temps[] = { 72.5, 73.4, 74.7, 75.2, 0.0 };
```

While you can use a value other than `0.0` as your sentinel value, using a sentinel value might not be desirable, so you might not really want to take the same approach as one does for strings.

For an array (as opposed to a pointer), you can use the following to determine the number of elements in the array:

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)
```

That means you can use the following to determine the number of elements in `temps`:

```
sizeof(temps)/sizeof(*temps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple method is to get the size of a array is by `sizeof(temps)/sizeof(temps[0])`

something like,

```
for(x = 0; x < sizeof(temps)/sizeof(temps[0]); x++){
        printf("Station %d: %.1f\n",x,temps[x]);
    }
```

**Note**: In your snippet array access is done from 1 to (size) instead 0 to (size-1) which is out of bound access.

Comment: When you tell people about using `sizeof x / sizeof *x` to get the size of an array, advise them it works only for arrays, not for pointers, to ward off the mistake made much too frequently by students.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this to get the length of your float array,

```
int main()
{
    float ar[4] = {1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4};
    float b;
    printf("Array Size : %d\n",sizeof(ar)/sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

You'll get the total number of element of your array , which you can use further in a loop to print the elements of array.
Note: Do not Use sizeof in case of pointers.

Comment: When you tell people about using `sizeof array / sizeof element` to get the size of an array, advise them it works only for arrays, not for pointers, to ward off the mistake made much too frequently by students.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

`strlen` expects an argument of type `char *`, which points to the first character of a *string*, which is a sequence of character values including a zero-valued *terminator*.  `strlen` returns the number of characters before the terminator:

```
/**
 * A naive implementation of strlen.  Actual implementations
 * are a little more clever.
 */
size_t strlen( const char *str )
{
  size_t count = 0;
  while( str[count] )
   count++; 
 return count;
}
```

The important thing to remember is that `strlen` returns the length of the string, not the size of the array containing the string.  If you have something like

```
char foo[1024] = “bar”;
```

the `strlen( foo );` returns 3.

If you tried to pass an integer or floating point array to `strlen` the compiler would yell at you because of the wrong argument type.  You could work around this by casting the argument to `char *`, but you would still likely get a wrong answer, not only because integer and float types are multiple `char`s wide, but also because such a value may have an embedded zero-valued byte.  For example, the integer value 16 is represented as the bytes `0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10`.  If that’s the first element of your integer array, then `strlen` would return 0 on a big-endian platform and 1 on a little-endian platform.

If you defined the array, then you know how big it is. If you’re writing a function that receives an array argument, then you must either also receive the size as a separate argument, or you must rely on the presence of a sentinel value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

strlen() takes a "const char *" type value as argument. So it cannot be used with integer or float arrays.